# edit user profile in django without typing password

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication, django-users

here I am trying to allow users to make modifications to their user profile. There's a model called UserProfile that holds a one to one relationship to django user itself. Below is the code in views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=profile)

        if profile_form.is_valid():

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']
            profile.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect("/me/login/")

        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors
    else:
        user = request.user
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(initial={'website':profile.website,'address':profile.address, 'picture':profile.picture})

    return render(request, 'member/edit_profile.html', {'profile_form': profile_form})
```

However, once the submit button is clicked from the template, I got an error saying that a password is needed.

```
[27/Apr/2015 14:25:07] "GET /me/edit_profile2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5080
<ul class="errorlist"><li>username<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>password<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul> 
[27/Apr/2015 14:25:16] "POST /me/edit_profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6384
```

from the code, I thought that the UserProfile is already bound to a specific user already, and I am only allowing users to make changes on the UserProfile model without touching django's auth User model. I wonder why the username and password is still needed in this case. Would it be possible to allow editing on user profile without users' password?

Here is the UserProfile extended from the User model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # link user profile to the user models
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar', blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)

    @property
    def stats(self):
        """get statistics for this profile"""
        from tumboon.models import Donation
        return Donation.statistics.for_user(self)

    @property
    def amount_donated(self):
        __doc__ = """get the total amount donated """
        return self.stats['total_amount_donated']

    # Override the __unicode__ to return something meaningful
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form for User Registration"""

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        widgets = {
            'username' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Username'}),
            'email'    : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Email'}),
            'password'    : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Password'}),            
        }

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form for UserProfile"""
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('website', 'picture', 'address')
```

And the UserProfileForm on the template is here:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <form id="user_profile" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/me/edit_profile/"> 
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h3>User Info</h3>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2" for="{{ user_form.picture.id_for_label }}">Picture: </label>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    {{profile_form.picture|add_class:"form-control"}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2" for="{{ user_form.website.id_for_label }}">Website: </label>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    {{profile_form.website|add_class:"form-control"}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2" for="{{ user_form.address.id_for_label }}">Address: </label>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    {{profile_form.address|add_class:"form-control"}}</li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="save_button" value="Save Profile">
        </form>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please post your `UserProfileForm`

Comment: You can you post the Python class `UserProfileForm`? I just see the `UserForm`.

Comment: Hi Aebersold, I just added the UserProfileForm here.

Comment: Are you sure that your view is serving the right form? And that your URL is hitting the right view? Can you show your view and your urls.py?

Comment: Do you have a form for the main user model on the same page? Could be that you're sending both. At any rate, you're using the wrong template tags in some of the html you posted. For instance, `<label class="col-xs-2" for="{{ user_form.picture.id_for_label }}">` should be `<label class="col-xs-2" for="{{ profile_form.picture.id_for_label }}">`

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are right; there's actually a typo at urls.py, which corrupted the POST method since it kind of sent the form data to nowhere. I got it fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Your UserForm class is extending Model.Form class which displays the Password field as required, hence the problem. Use instead the UserChangeForm:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

class UserForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_super_admin')
```

This form handles password as it should.

Comment: My form extends UserChangeForm but I still have this problem. What am I doing wrong?